# Docker image on Google Compute Engine wont run on port 80

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, next.js

I am deploying my Next.js / Nginx docker image from Container Registry to Compute Engine

Once deployed the application is running as expected, but its running on port 3000 instead of 80 - i.e. I want to access it at `<ip_address>` but I can only access it on `<ip_address>:3000`. I have setup a reverse proxy in Nginx to forward port 3000 to 80 but it does not seem to be working.

When I run `docker-compose up` the app is accessible on `localhost` (rather than `localhost:3000`)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine as react-build

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --global pm2

COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build
# EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  nextjs: 
    build: ./
  nginx: 
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

**./nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

# Remove any existing config files
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Copy config files
# *.conf files in "conf.d/" dir get included in main config
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

**./nginx/default.conf**

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

server {
  listen 80;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  # BUILT ASSETS (E.G. JS BUNDLES)
  # Browser cache - max cache headers from Next.js as build id in url
  # Server cache - valid forever (cleared after cache "inactive" period)
  location /_next/static {
    #proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  # STATIC ASSETS (E.G. IMAGES)
  # Browser cache - "no-cache" headers from Next.js as no build id in url
  # Server cache - refresh regularly in case of changes
  location /static {
    #proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://locahost:3000;
  }

  # DYNAMIC ASSETS - NO CACHE
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://locahost:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're proxying it correctly? Shouldn't the app dockerfile expose 3000 and nginx proxy it to 80? Looks like you're exposing 80 instead. That's why your app is accessible at localhost instead of localhost:3000. If thats so, your nginx proxy wouldn't work as its looking at localhost:3000. So your proxy is probably configured wrongly some where or the docker file is set to expose 3000 in production somehow.